# How to fix "local class incompatible" error in Spring?

Tags: java, spring-boot, redis

I'm using "Eclipse IDE for Enterprise Java Developers" and Spring version 2.1.6.RELEASE.

**Getting this error** *

> "There was an unexpected error (type=Internal Server Error,
>   status=500). Cannot deserialize; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.core.serializer.support.SerializationFailedException:
>   Failed to deserialize payload. Is the byte array a result of
>   corresponding serialization for DefaultDeserializer?; nested exception
>   is java.io.InvalidClassException:
>   com.tradingsimulator.FXTradingSimulator.models.Trade; local class
>   incompatible: stream classdesc serialVersionUID = 1938418202521727973,
>   local class serialVersionUID = 1"

- **when I try to fetch all the data from redis. Storing in redis is working fine, though.**

Here is my Model code:

```
public class Trade implements Serializable {

    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    String BaseCurr;
    String TradeCurr;
    String Quantity;
    String Price;
    String flag;

    //Constructor code is here

    //Getter Setter methods are here    
}
```

Any help? Thanks

I already tried changing the version of spring, but nothing worked.

Redis Dependency, I'm using -

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-redis-reactive</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

**EDIT:**

**Solved the issue just by flushing the Redis database.**

Comment: Are you using redis as cache or a message broker where one service (or instance) writes and another reads?

Comment: I am using Redis as cache here.